# PHP preg_replace NULL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

PHP `preg_replace("/[^\w\.\-]+/ig", "-", $string)` always gives me null. I really don't know, what's wrong. I initially had `0-9a-zA-Z` instead of `\w`, but nothing works.

Comment: What is in the $string variable ?

Comment: when I put there for example "something", it returns NULL. variable is form POST, I verified that there is right

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting some PHP error which you're suppressing because there is no global modifier `g` in PHP regex. Just use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w.-]+/', "-", $string);
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.